# Multiple -Re-invites from UA with incremented Cseq Handling

Tags: sip, voip

I have this scenario:

```
INVITE ----------> 1 Cseq invite
100 <---------- 
180 <---------- 
200 <---------- 
ACK ----------> Call 1 ACK connected
Pause [ 2000ms] 
INVITE ----------> 2Cseq Re-Invite
100 <---------- 
Pause [ 500ms] 
INVITE ----------> 3 Caseq Re-Invite
100 <---------- 
500 <---------- 500 3 cseq response for 3 Re-invite
200 <---------- 200 2 Cseq OK received for 2 nd ReInvite
ACK ----------> Ack of 3 cseq 500 -> here the state in SM is waiting ACK -> connected ACK 
ACK ---------> * Now here Connected ACK>Connected ACK ->Error - This is the issue. *
BYE ----------> 
200 <----------
```

I read in RFC : 5407

3.1.5.  Callee Receives re-INVITE (Established State) While in the
        Moratorium State (Case 2)

```
   State  Alice                          Bob  State
          |                                |
          |    ini-INVITE (no offer) F1    |
          |------------------------------->|
     Pre  |             180 F2             |  Pre
          |<-------------------------------|
     Ear  |                                |  Ear
          |    200(ini-INV) w/offer1 F3    |
          |<-------------------------------|
    Mora  |  ACK w/answer1 F4(packet loss) |  Mora
          |-------------------->x          |
     Est  |                                |
          | re-INVITE F6      200 F5(=F3)  |
          |   w/offer2         w/offer1    |
          |-------------     --------------|
          |              \ /               |
          |               X                |
          |              / \               |
          |<------------     ------------->|
          | ACK F7(=F4)      491/500(re-INV) F8|
          |-------------     --------------|
          |              \ /               |
          |               X                |
          |              / \               |
          |<------------     ------------->|
          |        ACK (re-INV) F9         |  Est
          |------------------------------->|
          |                                |
```

I do See that if we find a Re-invite in Preceding state we will send 500 with same endpoint for this.

My question is :

The above scenarios seems not valid as 2nd Re-Invite with Cseq 3 is sent before any final response .

Should We cater this scenario?If yes , should we Drop Re-Invite and not send 500. As 500 is sent in the RFC Diagram when ACK is sent from UA and is dropped in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear what the issue is and what the consequences are. However, it is clear that the UAC (the left hand side) is misbehaving. From RFC 3261 section 14.1:

> Note that a UAC MUST NOT initiate a new INVITE transaction within a
>   dialog while another INVITE transaction is in progress in either
>   direction.
>
> 1. If there is an ongoing INVITE client transaction, the TU MUST
>        wait until the transaction reaches the completed or terminated
>        state before initiating the new INVITE.
> 2. If there is an ongoing INVITE server transaction, the TU MUST
>        wait until the transaction reaches the confirmed or terminated
>        state before initiating the new INVITE.

But when things go wrong, such as receiving a second INVITE before having responded to the first, the RFC says in section 14.2:

> A UAS that receives a second INVITE before it sends the final
>   response to a first INVITE with a lower CSeq sequence number on the
>   same dialog MUST return a 500 (Server Internal Error) response to the 
>   second INVITE and MUST include a Retry-After header field with a
>   randomly chosen value of between 0 and 10 seconds.

So all in all, yes, you should be able to handle the scenario you describe, and the response should be 500.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that there are issues with the CSeq here.
The CSeq have to be monolithically incremented inside a dialog only.
However it can start with any number.
So it is completely valid that the second INVITE is starting with CSeq 3.